# How to force a wordpress template to parse code instead of plain-text

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have recently installed a new template(more specifically SquirrelTheme - a free template) in my wordpress blog. It happens that I would like to have two buttons on my front page. Let's say button X and button Y. For creating these buttons I use a plugin called "MaxButtons" which allows you to easily create and manage a button and it's functions. After creating the said button, it gives you a shortcode that you can insert in your posts and pages - lets say [maxbutton id="1"] - to display it.

Unfortunately, after editing the template to my liking(removing divs I didn't intend to display), I can't seem to display these two buttons as the template parses plain-text, unlike the pages/posts apparently.

In case you are wondering how I am inserting the shortcode for the buttons, the template can be easily modified through the dashboard, in which I inserted the following in the field that dictates what is displayed on the specific part of my homepage:

```
[maxbutton id="1"]  [maxbutton id="2"]
```

Like I said before, instead of showing the buttons as intended, I just see exactly what I type in the box.

I believe this is caused by how the template parses the text, as it uses its own function(? - php _e('...')) to echo the text:

```
<div class="full_content">
    <center>
    <?php if (squirrel_get_option('squirrel_slidehead') != '') { ?>
        <h1><?php echo stripslashes(squirrel_get_option('squirrel_slidehead')); ?></h1>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h1><?php _e('We are scope, a design firm in England', 'squirrel'); ?></h1>
    <?php } ?>            
    <?php if (squirrel_get_option('squirrel_slidedesc') != '') { ?>
        <h2><?php echo stripslashes(squirrel_get_option('squirrel_slidedesc')); ?></h2>            
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p><?php _e('Newfoundland dogs are good to save children from drowning, but you must have a pond of water handy and a child.', 'squirrel') ?></p>
        <p><?php _e('From drowning, but you must have a pond of water handy and a child.', 'squirrel'); ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
    </center>    
    </div>
```

My question is, how can I get it to display the buttons or any other code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the function [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) to do the proper [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) processing on some text.

Example:

```
echo do_shortcode('This is a button: [maxbutton id="1"]');
```

Comment: Thank you for reading through my wall of text and replying so quickly and accurately :) I have one more question though, if you don't mind replying ofcourse. How can I display one button next to another? Because if I do it like "<?php echo do_shortcode('This is a button: [maxbutton id="1"] [maxbutton id="2"]'); ?>" it will just display one button on top of another. Thank you once again :)

Comment: @user1298923: That's hard to say without seeing the generated HTML. It's probably worth asking in a different question, however.